# Помощь с Semantic UI

Tags: html, jquery, semantic-ui

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста почему может не работать выпадающий список [Compact Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)  если сделать append всего блока.

То есть у меня есть блок в коде html:

```
<div class="ui compact selection dropdown">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="text">Compact</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

который я добавил, есть кнопка "Add more" при нажатии на которую я с помощью append(); добавляю блок html

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#add-more").click(function () {
        $(".choose-category-block").append('<div class="ui compact selection dropdown" tabindex="0"><i class="dropdown icon"></i><div class="text">Choose Category</div><div class="menu"><div class="item">Dresses</div><div class="item">Jackets</div><div class="item">Jeans</div><div class="item">Shirts</div></div></div>');
    });
});
```

но первый выпадающий список, который добавлен в html откривается, а тот, который добавил с помощью append() не работает. В чём может быть проблема и какое возможное решение данного вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно инициализировать компонент.

```
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

Comment: я сделал инициализацию, иначе и первый выпадающий список, который добавлен изначально в html не ратобал бы

Comment: Всё верно, но при append ты вставляешь просто кусок кода на страницу. Что б этот кусок кода заработал тебе нужно вызвать для него инициализацию.

Comment: а как вызвать инициализацию для вставленного с помощью append(); куска кода на странице. Я инициализирую в файле,  а как сделать непосредственно на странице?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, разобрался. Как и говорил [Simonov Dmitro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/234296/simonov-dmitro), нужно добавить инициализацию для добавленного элемента, так как он динамически добавлен с помощью `append();`:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    $("#add-category").on("click", function(){
        $(".choose-category-block").append('<div class="ui compact selection dropdown" tabindex="0"><i class="dropdown icon"></i><div class="text">Choose Category</div><div class="menu"><div class="item">Dresses</div><div class="item">Jackets</div><div class="item">Jeans</div><div class="item">Shirts</div></div></div>');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
        }, 300);
    })
});
```